# Nativescript looking for Nativescript-theme-core in the wrong place?

Tags: css, angular, nativescript

I am busy with a very simple barcode scanner app and getting a strange error after the app gets deployed to a genymotion emulator...  It seems like it's looking for the core theme in the wrong place?  Any idea why this is happening and how I can try fix it?

my error:

```
JS: ns-renderer: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
JS: ns-renderer: File /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css does not exist. Resolved from: nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css.
JS:
JS: Error: File /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css does not exist. Resolved from: nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css.
JS:     at FileSystemResourceLoader.get (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js:22:19)
JS:     at DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13661:45)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13761:55
JS:     at Array.map (native)
JS:     at DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13761:16)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13764:28
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:190:28)
JS:     at Zone.run (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:83:43)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:449:57
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone.js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:223:37)

my app.css:

@import 'nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css';

and in my app.component.css:

    styleUrls: ['./app.css']
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ***app.css*** you should have

```
@import 'nativescript-theme-core/css/core.dark.css';
```

And in your ***app.component.ts*** remove the explicit call to app.css.
It is not needed as the styles in app.css will be visible globally in your application by default. See [this comment](https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/issues/122#issuecomment-267341381) for details.